# Value empty in password text box rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

`<%=password_field 'email_setting','emailpasswd' %>`

In this @email_setting.emailpasswd has the value password(@email_setting.emailpasswd="password").

But in email_setting form edit  the password text box is loaded with empty.Instead of that I need to show some characters(#######) to indicate that the  password is already entered.

I'm using Rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security precaution of Rails that password fields are not prepopulated. Otherwise they would be visible in plain text in page source.

If you really want to display it there though, you need to bypass form helpers and fallback to plain HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="email_setting[emailpasswd]" value="<%= @email_setting.emailpasswd %>" />
```

However that will not work well if you have your passwords hashed. You can't "decrypt" a hashed password, so you can't show them in plain text here.

Answer (score 3):

`password_field` renders with `nil` value by default. This makes the use of passwords secure by default. If you want to render the value of the `password_field`, you have to do for instance

```
f.password_field(:password, :value => @user.password)
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1851af84c1c7244dc416be9c93a4700b70e801e3

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like this:

In /config/initializers/my_constants.rb, set a constant with the value that you'd like to display to the user in the password input box.

```
STARS_PASSWORD = '*******'
```

In the User model, create a method that we will call from the form to determine what to display to the user inside the password input box.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def password_form_value
        password.present? ? STARS_PASSWORD : ''
    end
end
```

In the form, display the STARS_PASSWORD as the value on the input form, if in fact the user has already set a password.

```
<%=form.password_field :password, :value => @user.password_form_value %>
```

In the UsersController, delete the submitted password before updating if the submitted password is STARS_PASSWORD.

```
params[:user].delete :password if params[:user][:password] == STARS_PASSWORD
```

NB: If you have a password validator on the User model (for example, the password needs to have letters and numbers), you will also need to modify that validator to allow STARS_PASSWORD.